# Fetch all() isn't working in Anchor Client

Tags: anchor, anchor-client, fetch

I am trying to fetch all accounts owned by my program using `all()` method but it is giving me this nasty error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
at AccountClient.all
```

Code:

```
const accounts = await program.account.user.all();
```

It works if I try to fetch a single account like this:

```
const account = await program.account.user.fetch(new PublicKey("..."));
```

Comment: try removing the brackets in `.all()` , `await program.account.user.all()`. Unless you're trying to use `memcmp`

Comment: hey @john, I already tried the function without brackets. It is still the same error.

Comment: has the `user` account struct in your program been updated before? (ex. added new fields)

Comment: Thanks @john. The error was indeed due to the addition of new fields. Some accounts were created with the old struct fields, hence the client wasn't able to deserialize the old accounts correctly. Can you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment above, it seems that the problem was due to the `User` account struct being modified in the program after some accounts were already created.

For instance, suppose the `User` struct  was first defined in the following way, and several accounts were created:

```
#[account]
pub struct User {
pub user: Pubkey,
pub email: String,
}
```

Then, the program was updated to add a new field to the `User` struct:

```
#[account]
pub struct User {
pub user: Pubkey,
pub email: String,
pub name: String,
}
```

In this scenario, invoking `await program.account.user.all()` would result in an error because older accounts lack the new field and cannot be deserialized using the updated `User` struct.